# Why Can't I Save Many to Many table with Different Column Value in Sequelize?

Tags: mysql, database, sequelize.js

I have 2 tables with many to many relationships through an intersection table.

Products --> Orders <-- Outlets

This is what Sequelize generates

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Orders` (`id` INTEGER auto_increment , `amount` INTEGER, `orderDate` DATETIME, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `OutletId` INTEGER, `ProductId` INTEGER, `UserId` INTEGER, UNIQUE `Orders_ProductId_OutletId_unique` (`OutletId`, `ProductId`), PRIMARY KEY (`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`OutletId`) REFERENCES `Outlets` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY (`ProductId`) REFERENCES `Products` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY (`UserId`) REFERENCES `Users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I know it creates a unique key: UNIQUE Orders_ProductId_OutletId_unique (OutletId, ProductId).

That's why I can't save, them with the same OutletId and ProductId, however, my case, OutletId and ProductId can be the same, but the orderDate must be different.

So I save this is okay,

```
OrderId, ProductId, OutletId, orderDate
1, 1, 1, '2016-1-1'
2, 2, 1, '2016-1-1'
```

However, when I save another row:

```
1, 1, 1, '2016-1-2'
```

MySql gives me this error:

```
ERROR 1062: 1062: Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'Orders_ProductId_OutletId_unique'
```

Ok, so the question is, how can I create the model that has this validation or constraint?

Here are my models:

### Order

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

    var Order = sequelize.define('Order', {
            id: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: true
            },
            amount: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            orderDate: DataTypes.DATE
        },
        {
            associate: function(models){
                Order.belongsTo(models.Outlet);
                Order.belongsTo(models.Product);
                Order.belongsTo(models.User);
            }
        }
    );

    return Order;
};
```

### Product

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

    var Product = sequelize.define('Product', {
            inventoryCode: DataTypes.STRING,
            name: DataTypes.STRING,
            nameKh: DataTypes.STRING,
            unitKh: DataTypes.STRING,
            unit: DataTypes.STRING,
            monthlyCaseTarget: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            pieces: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            star: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
            price: DataTypes.FLOAT,
            active: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
        },
        {
            associate: function(models){
                Product.belongsToMany(models.Outlet, {through: models.Order});
                Product.belongsTo(models.Category);
                // Product.hasMany(models.Order);
            }
        }
    );

    return Product;
};
```

### Outlets

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

    var Outlet = sequelize.define('Outlet', {
            outletCode: DataTypes.STRING,
            outletName: DataTypes.STRING,
            outletNameKh: DataTypes.STRING,
            outletSubtype: DataTypes.STRING,
            perfectStoreType: DataTypes.STRING,
            address: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        {
            associate: function(models){
                Outlet.belongsToMany(models.Product, {through: models.Order});
                Outlet.belongsTo(models.Distributor);
                // Outlet.hasMany(models.Order);
            }
        }
    );

    return Outlet;
};
```

Comment: is this mysql or SQL server? dont tag products you arent using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since sequelize produces this query:

```
UNIQUE Orders_ProductId_OutletId_unique (OutletId, ProductId)
```

so I kinda hack it by adding the composite unique key to the order column.

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

    var Order = sequelize.define('Order', {
            id: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: true
            },
            amount: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER
            },
            orderDate: {
                type: DataTypes.DATE,
                unique: 'Orders_ProductId_OutletId_unique'
            }
        },
        {
            associate: function(models){
                Order.belongsTo(models.Outlet);
                Order.belongsTo(models.Product);
                Order.belongsTo(models.User);
            }
        }
    );

    return Order;
};
```